# Sencha Touch - NestedList shows up only after rotation

Tags: rotation, sencha-touch, nested-lists

I've been playing around with sencha touch a little and I've encountered a problem.
I have a tabbed UI and one tab has the xtype 'pastcard' defined by the following code:

```
    var data = {
    text: 'Groceries',
    items: [{
        text: 'Drinks',
        items: [{
            text: 'Water',
            items: [{
                text: 'Sparkling',
                leaf: true
            },{
                text: 'Still',
                leaf: true
            }]
        },{
            text: 'Coffee',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Espresso',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Redbull',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Coke',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Diet Coke',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Fruit',
        items: [{
            text: 'Bananas',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Lemon',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Snacks',
        items: [{
            text: 'Nuts',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Pretzels',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Wasabi Peas',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Empty Category',
        //items: []
    }]
};
Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
    fields: [{name: 'text', type: 'string'}]
});
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'ListItem',
    root: data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
var nestedList = new Ext.NestedList({
    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Groceries',
    displayField: 'text',
    dock: 'top',
    store: store
});
    metanamorph.views.Pastcard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    title: "past",
    iconCls: "add",
    dockedItems: nestedList
});

Ext.reg('pastcard', metanamorph.views.Pastcard);
```

In my Desktop Browser this works fine, but on my iPhone and the iPhone Simulator the 'past' site contains the List 'Groceries' but doesn't show any list items. However if I rotate the Device the List shows. This is probably because there is some sort of refresh on rotate.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: first check if the rotation is causing the refresh or is it maybe the change in the height and width. If its the second, then try calling a setWidth and setHeight function once in your code, and seeing if it works.

Comment: Also, what is `proxy : { type : 'memory' . . . }` ??